# update all rows where there is a fk constraint issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm migrating a table into a new database. There is a fk constraint problem because there was never a relationship set between the 2 tables (tbl_contacts.contact_ID and tbl_communications.contact_ID which is the fk). I can see all the rows with

```
SELECT * FROM Farm.tbl_communication as S
LEFT JOIN Farm.tbl_contacts ON S.contact_ID = Farm.tbl_contacts.contact_ID
WHERE Farm.tbl_contacts.contact_ID IS NULL
```

I was just trying to delete those rows and I tried this:

```
    DELETE FROM Farm.tbl_communication 
    WHERE Farm.tbl_communication.contact_ID (SELECT contact_ID
    FROM ( SELECT * FROM Farm.tbl_communication) as S
    LEFT JOIN Farm.tbl_contacts ON S.contact_ID = Farm.tbl_contacts.contact_ID
    WHERE Farm.tbl_contacts.contact_ID IS NULL)
```

Which did not work. I have now thought better of it and I'm going to create a catch-all contact so I'll update all the communications.contact_ID with the new catch-all id. The problem is I have no idea how to go about that. what would the syntax be?

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Is your question about the delete or the update?

Comment: The question is about the update. The delete seems a little extreme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM Farm.tbl_communication
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM  Farm.tbl_contacts
    WHERE Farm.tbl_contacts.contact_ID = Farm.tbl_communication.contact_ID);
```

...or you can update them by changing the DELETE bit to UPDATE.

Comment: So would I change delete to update and then tack on the end `SET Farm.tbl_communication.contact_ID = 999`?

Comment: Yes. You'd have: `UPDATE Farm.tbl_communication SET contact_ID = 999 WHERE...` - but be careful about using 999. What happens if you get that many contacts? Maybe use -1 instead, or simply NULL.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you kind Sir. For the new contact_ID I found one that must have been deleted and didn't have anything associated with it and used that.